# Cannot make passport-saml work with ADFS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml-2.0, adfs

I have implemented SSO with ADFS on a NodeJS application using express, passport and passport-saml. I can login on ADFS and I'm correctly posted back to my callback route (which is localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse) together with a SAML-token. However, when I reach the callback route, it seems like the SAML-token is rejected so I'm sent back to login on ADFS. This is then repeated.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

More details:

This SAML request is sent to ADFS:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse"
    Destination="https://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/ls" ID="_5e09625f5c3f5dbb0b6b"
    IssueInstant="2018-06-28T11:57:35.962Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">acme_tools_com</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

This SAML response is POSTED from the ADFS server to my callback https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse:

```
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse" ID="_e543e979-0d99-48fe-947f-1d1469da8c70"
    InResponseTo="_49ab1e1060c3d7849902" IssueInstant="2018-06-28T19:46:27.782Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_cf245f57-1380-47cd-a5d3-05b13e4d9416" IssueInstant="2018-06-28T19:46:27.782Z"
        Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_cf245f57-1380-47cd-a5d3-05b13e4d9416">
                    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>r6voAsVq4yAJTn4BQLFsyaoiCK3b7KQbJ5jVqi53ceY=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>F55JA6jNp3qFfp7p/BSzQBRTtVPOlQvIfVNG3JiqjohVC7Et0+aiRVlHHvZNghPJxhmxhuAUbo2kOweN+lZKb+fqDgK51kZ/DrIVpkljmwP2gJYgOGpJti53wfH2qkdDsxNkR3e13mG7RKwBuA4gJ0NxUFshmxyun0HKefd10wjnFwHY6dELWFmTL1W5xd2ZF/98ahIaqEWAMCYsJewEg4ND8z4vG74miht3lWHfTJL6kQ0UGkTJVwGZy9L8zaY8AMDRujs8SlXvBx9nvUnvufpYqto4kd0O0USWMCOPipcF2sVYDOVzidRSRb79TK256Wg9EGiw1usVThfAJ8IBzQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <Subject>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_49ab1e1060c3d7849902"
                NotOnOrAfter="2018-06-28T19:51:27.782Z" Recipient="https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2018-06-28T19:46:27.781Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-06-28T20:46:27.781Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>acme_tools_com</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-06-28T19:45:51.797Z">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

NB: The SAML request and response can be inspected using the SAML Chrome extension.

The most central part of my NodeJS program is this:

```
const verifyFunction = function(profile, done) {
    console.log("Verifying"+ profile);
    return done(null,
        {
            upn: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn'],
            // e.g. if you added a Group claim
            group: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group']
        });
};

var strategy = new SamlStrategy(
    {
        entryPoint: 'https://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/ls',
        issuer: 'acme_tools_com',
        callbackUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse',
        privateCert: fs.readFileSync(root + '/acme_tools_com.key', 'utf-8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(root + '/acme_tools_com.cert', 'utf-8'),
        authnContext: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password',
        // not sure if this is necessary?
        acceptedClockSkewMs: -1,
        identifierFormat: null,
        signatureAlgorithm: 'sha256'
    },
    verifyFunction
);

strategy.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
    console.log("UserProfile:" + accessToken);
    done(null, accessToken);
};


passport.use('provider', strategy);
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Serializing user");
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Deserializing user");
    done(null, user);
});



app.get('/login',
    passport.authenticate('provider', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true })
);
app.post('/adfs/postResponse',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Before authenticating: " );
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('provider', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log("User: " + util.inspect(req.user));
        res.cookie('accessToken', req.user);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

When doing the login I see no errors on the ADFS server, so it looks good there.

On the NodeJS server I see:

```
Express server started on https://localhost:3000 
postResponse entered:
postResponse entered:
...
```

In other words, verifyFunction is never called. Isn't that strange? It seems like the passport-saml module does not pick up the SAML response.

The POST from ADFS to my callback is the following:

```
curl 'https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse' -H 'Origin: https://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: https://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/ls?SAMLRequest=nVJLc9owEP4rHt2xZMdD....' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,da;q=0.8' -H  --data 'SAMLResponse=PHNhbWxwOlJlc3.......' --compressed --insecure
```

This is the NodeJS program in full length:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('express')();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var fs = require('fs');
var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
var path = require("path");

const root = __dirname;
const verifyFunction = function(profile, done) {
    console.log("Verifying"+ profile);
    return done(null,
        {
            upn: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn'],
            // e.g. if you added a Group claim
            group: profile['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group']
        });
};

var strategy = new SamlStrategy(
    {
        entryPoint: 'https://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/ls',
        issuer: 'acme_tools_com',
        callbackUrl: 'https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse',
        privateCert: fs.readFileSync(root + '/acme_tools_com.key', 'utf-8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(root + '/acme_tools_com.cert', 'utf-8'),
        authnContext: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password',
        // not sure if this is necessary?
        acceptedClockSkewMs: -1,
        identifierFormat: null,
        signatureAlgorithm: 'sha256'
    },
    verifyFunction
);

strategy.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
    console.log("UserProfile:" + accessToken);
    done(null, accessToken);
};


passport.use('provider', strategy);
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Serializing user");
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Deserializing user");
    done(null, user);
});

function validateAccessToken(accessToken) {
    console.log("AccessToken: "+ accessToken);
    return;
}


// Configure express app
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get('/login',
    passport.authenticate('provider', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true })
);
app.post('/adfs/postResponse',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Before authenticating: " );
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('provider', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log("User: " + util.inspect(req.user));
        res.cookie('accessToken', req.user);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.user = req.cookies['accessToken'];
    res.send(
        !req.user ? '<a href="/login">Log In</a>' : '<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>' +
        '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(req.user, null, 2) + '</pre>');
});
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    res.clearCookie('accessToken');
    res.redirect('/');
});

var certOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(root + '/localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(root + '/localhost.cert')
}

var server = https.createServer(certOptions, app).listen(3000)
console.log('Express server started on https://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: You've posted the request twice. Please post the response.

Comment: Thx, I added the response.

Comment: The status is Responder which means an error. What does the ADFS event log show? Also it look like ADFS is using SHA256 but SAML is normally SHA1. You can change this on the RP on the Advanced tab.

Comment: Regarding SHA256: SHA256 is chosen in ADFS on the RP Advanced tab. So I assumed this would be fine. I'll try changing it to SHA1.

Comment: The ADFS event log only shows this error which is caused by the login-loop between my app and ADFS: Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '1' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.

Comment: I see this error earlier in the ADFS log, but it does not appear during my login attempts: 

Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls to process the incoming request.

Comment: A closer look at the login-loop shows that the first SAML-response is actually different. I updated the post to reflect all these details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be really simple. I needed to include middleware to parse POST data.

After adding these lines to the top of my NodeJS module it worked.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Just a question. How did you simulate ADFS on your server?